# Including Smarty templates from sub-folders using relative paths

Tags: smarty

I have created a folder structure for smarty templates

```
f 
.f1 
..template1.tpl 
..test.tpl 
template1.tpl
```

the template_dir path is pointed to folder 'f/'

in test.tpl is the code below

```
{include file="template1.tpl"} 
{include file="../template1.tpl"}
```

This code does not work. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

I read about $smarty-> use_sub_dirs = true, which did create subfolders in my template_c folder but I'm still not able to include templates as per the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to solve this myself. The idea was to do a {include file="f1/template1.tpl"} {include file="template1.tpl"}

Answer (score 4):

just add f1 to your URL

{include file="f1/template1.tpl"}